# How to call component's function from service?

Tags: angular, typescript

In a component I have a spinner with two functions: `showSpinner()` and `stopSpinner()`. When I call `postToken()` in the components, this will call the `postToken()` function of the service. In the service's `postToken()` function, I want to call the function `showSpinner()` from the component to show the spinner in the view (and also stop the spinner).

My code is currently a mess, because I have tried to apply different kind of solutions from Google/StackOverflow, so bear with me :P.

**component.ts**

```
export class AuthenticatetokenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

  public showSpinner() {
    this.spinner.show();
  }

  public stopSpinner() {
    this.spinner.hide();
  }

  private postToken() {
    this.authService.postToken(this.token);
  }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private BASE_URL: string = "http://localhost:8080";

  constructor(private authenticateToken: AuthenticatetokenComponent, private _router: Router, private _dataservice: DataService) { }

  postToken(token: string) : void {
    this.authenticateToken.showSpinner();

    if(this.authenticateToken.token == '') {
      this.authenticateToken.stopSpinner();
      this.authenticateToken.openModal("Tokenveld is leeg! Voer aub een token in!");
    }

    this.authenticateToken.httpClient.post('/authentication', {
        token: token
     }
    ).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        if (token === '') {
          this.authenticateToken.stopSpinner();
          console.log('Khiem hier error in duwen');
          throw new Error('This token is not valid');
        } else {
          this.authenticateToken.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            this._dataservice.electionFromService = data;
            this._dataservice.tokenFromService = token;
            this.authenticateToken.stopSpinner();
            this._router.navigateByUrl('/voting-page');
        }
      }
    );
  }
  getRestCall() : void {
    this.authenticateToken.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/test')
      .subscribe(
        (data: any[]) => {
          this.authenticateToken.data = data;
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: So whats the problem ?

Comment: I suggest you to use your spinner service generally instead of using it in specific component. Try getting the spinner reference in service you want to call it instead of component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
export class AuthenticatetokenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

  public showSpinner() {
    this.spinner.show();
  }

  public stopSpinner() {
    this.spinner.hide();
  }

  private postToken() {
    this.showSpinner();
    this.authService.postToken(this.token).subscribe((response) => {
         this.stopSpinner();
    });
  }
}
```

---

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private BASE_URL: string = "http://localhost:8080";

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _dataservice: DataService, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  postToken(token: string): Observable<any> {

    return this.httpClient.post<any>('/authentication', {
      token: token
    }
    ).map(
      (data: any) => {
        return data.json();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Move the code inside subscription to the component;

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm getting: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: You might also need to suggest/specify OP to update his `postToken` method in service to return the subscription.

Comment: You need to update the service as well.. I'll update the answer wait.

Comment: Kinda works, but i'm getting : data.json is not a function. The service will post the token to the server and the server responds with an OK or 403. If OK gets returned, I want to do something, else if 403 gets returned, also do something.  Both cases should stop the spinner also. Could you help? Sorry i'm very noobish.

Comment: @Khiem the important part was returning the `Observable` that comes out of the `httpClient.post` function. What logic you apply onto the returned data (if any) is up to you. This answer has given you the information you need to be able to separate the concerns of your UI and service logic. The service shouldn't know anything about the components that use it.

Comment: Write a [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for this. From that you can intercept all the http requests and responses. And you can handle errors according to status of the response.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer you're expecting but I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your `AuthService` to begin with. Currently, its code almost exclusively uses properties and methods of your component which implies that it should rather be a part of your component. Put differently, you should be able to dispense with the service class.

If you are 100% sure, however, that you *do* need a service, I would suggest you try to avoid injecting the component as a dependency into your service as you currently do because this otherwise means that you're dealing with a circular dependency – which, sooner or later and in one way or the other, will lead you to hell. (Besides, services are meant to be independent of the component using them. That's kind of the point of having a service.)

Anyway, to avoid this circular dependency, i.e. to disentangle the component and the service and have the service not know about your component, I would suggest one the following:

- Have the component pass a callback to the service which contains all component-specific actions to be taken once the service is done, well, serving. The service can then invoke this callback when the time is right.
- Have the service's methods return the observable returned by the HTTPClient library, so that the component can subscribe to it, too, and execute custom code when the HTTP request terminates.

In both cases, you will need to inject HTTPClient as a dependency into your service instead of your component.

Comment: This is the right answer if you ask me :). I'd like to note that the second suggestion is the defacto standard. The first suggestion still couples the service to components that use it, in that the service needs to know when components expect the callback to be called. The second suggestion doesn't have such problem.

Comment: Regarding option 2 being the defacto standard, I mostly agree, though I'd say whether or not it's the right solution here still depends on whether the service wants to expose the data from the HTTP response to other subscribers. As for option 1 and your statement "that the service needs to know when components expect the callback to be called", I wouldn't say this couples the service to the components, though. It merely means that the service method's signature (in particular the callback's purpose) needs to be documented properly. But this is always the case when you introduce callbacks.